# How to assign Azure Pod Identity on local kubernetes(k8s) cluster (while developing)

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-aks, kubernetes-pod

I am developing an application which uses Pod Identity to connect to Azure Sql Database.

After deploying it on Azure Kubernetes Service (**AKS**), POD(application) connects to Azure Sql using PodIdentity (Managed Identity).

**How can I assign the same identity to POD while running on my local k8s cluster?**

My deployment yaml looks like

```
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: xxx
  labels:
    app: xxx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
     appName: xxx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        appName: xxx
        aadpodidbinding: samplepodidentity
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: xxx
        image: xxx
        env:
        - name: xxx
          value: "xxx"
        - name: UpdateDbTraceEndpoint
          value: "xxx"
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
```

**Update:---------------------------**

I tried the the [standard walk thru](https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/docs/demo/standard_walkthrough/) but still it is giving error.

[image]

**According to me MIC is not working on local K8s cluster**. How can I get it working?

Comment: Hi, is it that you want to assign the same managed identity(user or system) that you assigned to a pod in AKS cluster to a pod in local k8s cluster???? Or is it that you want to create a similar type of managed identity in local environment and assign it to a pod in k8s cluster??? Wanted some more clarification on it.

Comment: @KartikBhiwapurkar-MT doesn't matter if it is same identity or a sepearate Managed identity. whatever the choice is, requirment is to assign Identity to POD running on local K8s cluster so that It can use the identity to autheticate against other Azure resources.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can deploy [`aad-pod-identity`](https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/) on your local cluster using [helm](https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/docs/getting-started/installation/#helm) or the [YAML Deployment files](https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/docs/getting-started/installation/#quick-install).

The main difference is that you can't use some of the `az aks` commands and instead perform the steps manually like creating the `AzureIdentity` resource.

The [standard walkthrough](https://azure.github.io/aad-pod-identity/docs/demo/standard_walkthrough/) doc covers the details.

Comment: @PromodValavalaMSFT I tried the standard walk thru and still MIC is not working

Comment: Note that aad-pod-identity has been abandoned my MS in favor of Workload Identity https://github.com/Azure/aad-pod-identity#-announcement.

It also has critical security vulnerabilities according to https://artifacthub.io/packages/helm/aad-pod-identity/aad-pod-identity

Answer (score 0):

You can deploy azure-workload-identity, but it's not easy to set up and requires a public endpoint for OIDC federation: https://azure.github.io/azure-workload-identity/docs/installation/self-managed-clusters.html

You can handle the public endpoint by using a service such as [localtunnel or ngrok](https://dev.to/hookdeck/tools-i-use-in-my-webhook-development-workflow-1mkp).

The much easier solution is to provide connection strings to your services in your local environment through environment variables backed by secrets. But that won't use the same Managed Identity as your AKS deployed pod. However, you weren't going to get to use the same Federated Identity as the pod in AKS anyways, so why go through all that extra hassle just to verify that the Managed Identity has correct permissions?